# Why can't my bot get channels? discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I get this error in my console: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined`.

The code that is causing the problem:

```js
const channel = guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.type === 'text' && channel.permissionsFor(guild.me).has('SEND_MESSAGES'))
```

Index.js:

```js
client.on("guildCreate", guild => {
  client.commands.get("joinserver").execute(guild)
});
```

joinserver.js:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js")

module.exports = {
  name: 'joinserver',
  description: '',
  execute(message, args, client, guild) {
    const channel = guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.type === 'text' && channel.permissionsFor(guild.me).has('SEND_MESSAGES'))
    const embeds = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    channel.send(embeds)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You passing your `guild` object into the `execute` function as first parameter (which is not `guild` but `message` parameter). So your guild is accessible inside `execute` function as `message` right now. You should pass guild into correct argument (4th argument in your example) or change the way how `execute` function receiving arguments.

```js
client.on("guildCreate", guild => {
  // This should work: you need to pass null to `message`, `args` and `client`
  // because these arguments marked as required
  client.commands.get("joinserver").execute(null, null, null, guild)
});
```